# Unable to upload image in Visual studio code - Unexpected File location problem

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

I am having a hard time to upload the images. The error message does not make a sense to me. I saved the folder on my desktop and all photos are visible. Could anyone explain?

I saved the folder on my desk top, then the File location is described as : Desktop/img/img/cake1.jpg. Why "img" is duplicated? I cannot change the html since this is homework.

[image: html] [image: css] [image: error] [image: message] final format to be

Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the help pages, take the https://stackoverflow.com/tour. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: Please consider adding runnable example instead of code screenshots; using jsfiddle.net, codepen.io, plnkr.co etc or use 'stack snippets' by using by clicking the [<>] toolbar button in the edit section. This will help to better understand the problem, what you've already tried and the exact errors encountered.

Answer (score 1):

it seams that you want to load the images from your root path `/`. But in your HTML file you are using the path `img/<filename>.jpg`. Try to move your files into a new directory named `img` or adjust the path to `<filename>.jpg`

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I saved the folder on my desk top, then file location is listed as:  Desktop/img/img/cake1.jpg. Why img is duplicated? I cannot change the html since this is homework.